# SQLAlchemy - How do I SELECT x.id IS NOT NULL AS with a join?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a simple follow system similar to that of Twitter, so I have a table, which is a directed graph that consists of the following fields: **id, from_user (int), to_user (int)**

```
class Follower(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_follower'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    from_user = Column(ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    to_user = Column(ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

What I'm basically trying to achieve in SQLAlchemy is this:

```
SELECT f1.id, f1.from_user, f1.to_user, f2.id 
IS NOT NULL AS followed_back FROM user_follower f1 
left outer join user_follower f2 on f1.from_user = f2.to_user and f1.to_user = f2.from_user 
WHERE f1.to_user = :uid
```

In other words, I need to generate a column called followed_back that tells if a user is also following a follower.

This seems to be quite problematic in SQLAlchemy because there doesn't seem to be much in the documentation for creating SELECT AS statements along with joins. Also, I'm not really sure how one would reference the followed_back member variable once the object has been created by the query.

Comment: It's actually fairly trivial in sqlalchemy, but it would help if you would show your current code and query :)

Comment: Yah, my knowledge of sqlalchemy is very basic. All I have so far is this:
matching_follow = DBSession.query(Follower).filter(Follower.from_user == user_id)

Comment: Don't you have a table or model definition in sqlalchemy? If not, you should start with that :)

Comment: Sure, let me add it to the question.

Comment: I also tried executing it as a raw query, but unfortunately, all it did was perform the join. I'm not really sure where I would access the 'followed_back' attribute. (AttributeError: 'Follower' object has no attribute 'followed_back'.)

Comment: Having the `User` model as well could help, but I think this should be enough. I'll try to create an example for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Wolph's answer covers your question completely.

As an alternative: If your table `Follower` is only there to enable many-to-many relationship, you could model it somewhat *cleaner*:

```
users_followers = Table(
    'users_follower', Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('from_user', ForeignKey('user.id')),
    Column('to_user', ForeignKey('user.id')),
    UniqueConstraint('from_user', 'to_user', name='UC_users_follower'),
)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    followers = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=users_followers,
        primaryjoin=id == users_followers.c.to_user,
        secondaryjoin=id == users_followers.c.from_user,
        backref="followees",
        # cascade='all',
    )
```

In this case you could write your query as below:

```
U1 = aliased(User, name="u1")
U2 = aliased(User, name="u2")
q = (session
     .query(
         U1, U2,
         U2.followers.any(User.id == U1.id).label("followed_back"),
     )
     .join(U2, U1.followers)
     # .filter(...)
     # .order_by(...)
     )

for u1, u2, follows in q:
    print(u1, u2, follows)
```

This query is not going to be faster, but it is easier to relate to the model, and it gives you also other information about the users (name etc), which I assume you need to have anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This should roughly be the query you need:

```
f1 = aliased(Follower, name="f1")
f2 = aliased(Follower, name="f2")

query = (
    session
    .query(f1, (f2.id != None).label("followed_back"))
    .filter_by(to_user=...)
    .outerjoin(f2, (f1.from_user == f2.to_user) & (f1.to_user == f2.from_user))
)
```